# Rails 5 IntegrationTest with IP Geolocation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation, integration-testing, ruby-on-rails-5, geokit

I'm making use of the `geokit-rails` gem to perform geolocation based on the IP address of the user who is logging in via `#geocode_ip_address` (https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails#ip-geocoding-helper).

However, I'm having a very hard time finding a way to test this via the Rails 5 IntegrationTest.  I need a way to provide multiple remote IP addresses when simulating a login but I am stuck on the following issues:

- how to spoof an IP address (that will vary based on the user logging in)
- how to prevent making a ton of requests to the geolocation service

My original approach was to just skip it and place the `:geo_location` information in the `session` hash, however this seems to have gone away in Rails 5 per https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/23386.

Anybody have experience with a similar set-up?

Comment: are you using RSpec?

Comment: Test cases are using the built-in Minitest.

Answer (score 3):

As per implementation of the ip lookup in `geokit-rails` https://github.com/geokit/geokit-rails/blob/master/lib/geokit-rails/ip_geocode_lookup.rb#L44 you could simply stub the `remote_ip` method on the `request` object.

Once geokit-rails found a geo_location based on your IP it stores it as a `geo_location` object in the `session`. You might not want this "caching" behaviour in development/test, so I am deleting the object right before spoofing the IP.

Here an example implementation:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  prepend_before_action :spoof_remote_ip if: -> { %w(development test).include? Rails.env }
  geocode_ip_address

  def index
    @current_location = session[:geo_location]
  end

  def spoof_remote_ip
    session.delete(:geo_location) if session[:geo_location]
    request.env["action_dispatch.remote_ip"] = ENV['SPOOFED_REMOTE_ADDR']
  end
end
```

```
# .env
SPOOFED_REMOTE_ADDR = "xx.xxx.xx.xxx"
```

Comment: Thanks @Robin, looks like that could help with "how to spoof an IP address".  Any chance you have an example / have you actually implemented this?

Comment: @krsyoung A few days later I added an example to my answer. Only took me 2 years to let you know :D